# NDSolve runs out of memory

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, memory

I need to solve a second order ODE numerically. The ODE depends on two parameters (a,b). Things work fine when 'a' is small, but for large 'a' the solutions are oscillating rapidly and Mathematica takes a long time to solve or eventually just runs out of memory.

I need to integrate over quite a large range (10,000) and that is part of the problem, but I actually only need the value of the `InterpolatingFunction` produced at the end point. Is there a way to tell Mathematica I just want this last point? And not store the rest (very large) `InterpolatingFunction` in memory? i.e. just integrate so far, take that point use as ICs for next leg, then integrate to next pt, take that as IC and integrate onwards,etc...

Or just some other strategy for using `NDSolve` with such highly oscillatory solutions.

Some definitions:

```
M=1;
rstar[r_] := r + 2 M Log[r/(2 M) - 1];
$MinPrecision = 45;
wp = $MinPrecision;
ac = $MinPrecision - 8;
λ[l_] = l (l + 1);
rinf = 10000;
rH = 200001/100000;
nH = 200;
```

The ODE is:

```
eq[ω_, l_] := Φ''[r] + (2 (r - M))/(
 r (r - 2 M)) Φ'[
 r] + ((ω^2 r^2)/(r - 2 M)^2 - λ[l]/(
 r (r - 2 M))) Φ[r] == 0
```

Without going into detail about why I have these initial conditions, they are :

```
HorizonICs[l_?IntegerQ, ω_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{ΦinrH, dΦinrH},
 Clear[b];
   b[0] = 1; b[-1] = 0; b[-2] = 0;
   b[n_] := 
  b[n] = Simplify[
 1/(2 n (n - 4 I ω)) (-2 I ω b[-2 + n] + 
    2 I n ω b[-2 + n] + l b[-1 + n] + l^2 b[-1 + n] + 
    n b[-1 + n] - n^2 b[-1 + n] - 4 I ω b[-1 + n] + 
    8 I n ω b[-1 + n])];
  uintrunc[r_, n_] := Sum[b[i] (r - 2 M)^i, {i, 0, n}];
  ΦinrH = (Exp[-I ω rstar[rH]] uintrunc[rH, nH])/(
  2 M);
 dΦinrH = 
  D[(Exp[-I ω rstar[r]] uintrunc[r, nH])/(2 M), r] /. 
   r -> rH;
 ]
```

Solve as

```
ΦinExt[ωω_ , 
 l_] := ΦinExt[ωω, l] = Φ /. 
 NDSolve[{eq[ωω, l], Φ[rH] == 
    N[HorizonICs[l, ωω][[1]], wp], Φ'[
     rH] == N[HorizonICs[l, ωω][[2]], 
     wp]}, Φ, {r, rH, rinf}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  AccuracyGoal -> ac, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"][[1]];
```

You can also look for another solution that has the property of being simple near infinity and we set the ICs there. This is the particular solution that seems to be really really slow and causes memory crash.

Some definitions:

```
M = 1;
r0 = 5/2;
rstar[r_] := r + 2 M Log[r/(2 M) - 1];
$MinPrecision = 45;
wp = $MinPrecision;
ac = $MinPrecision - 8;
λ[l_] = l (l + 1);
rinf = 10000;
ninfphase = 
50;
```

Set init conditions:

```
Infinitycs = Module[{n = ninfphase, c}, 
Clear[c];
veqexp = 
CoefficientList[
 Series[(-2 - l r - l^2 r + 2 (r + I r^3 ω) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["v", "′",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r] + (-2 + r) r^2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["v", "′",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r]^2 + (-2 + r) r^2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["v", "′′",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r])/
   r /. {v'[r_] :> Sum[-i c[i]/r^(i + 1), {i, 1, n}], 
    v''[r_] :> 
     Sum[i (i + 1) c[i]/r^(i + 2), {i, 1, n}]}, {r, ∞, 
   n - 1}], r^-1];
Do[c[i] = c[i] /. Simplify[Solve[veqexp[[i]] == 0, c[i]][[1]]]; 
Print, {i, 1, n}] ;
Table[c[i], {i, 1, n}]];

InfinityICs[ll_?IntegerQ, ωω_?NumericQ] := Module[{c2},
Do[c2[i] = 
Infinitycs[[i]] /. {l -> ll, ω -> ωω}, {i, 1,
 ninfphase}];
vtrunc = Sum[c2[i]/r^i, {i, 1, ninfphase}];
init = 1/r Exp[I ωω rstar[r] + vtrunc] /. r -> rinf;
dinit = 
D[1/r Exp[I ωω rstar[r] + vtrunc], r] /. r -> rinf;
Clear[c2];
{init, dinit}]
```

Solve it

```
Φout[ωω_, 
l_] := Φout[ωω, l] = Φ /. 
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100}, 
  NDSolve[{eq[ωω, l], Φ[rinf] == 
     N[InfinityICs[l, ωω][[1]], wp], Φ'[
      rinf] == 
     N[InfinityICs[l, ωω][[2]], 
      wp]}, Φ, {r, rinf, r0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
   AccuracyGoal -> ac, MaxSteps -> ∞]][[1]];
```

Comment: You could partition the interval yourself ...

Comment: Sounds a bit like the `Burgers equation` (although that is a PDE). What does your equation look like? What does your mathematica code look like? I wonder if it is because of your history length in case you are using the `%` for the previous step. (Try setting $HistoryLength=0)

Comment: I added the ODE, it's the Klein-Gordon equation on Schwarzschild. I don't use % at all in code. It's just that the solutions to these equations get mega oscillatory as omega gets bigger, and I integrate over such a large range of 10000 in r, that I think the interpolatingfunction being generated starts to hog lots and lots of memory, as mathematica samples tonnes of points perhaps.

Comment: Do you mind including the boundary conditions perhaps. And the values of M and `omega` etc..

Comment: To repeat my question earlier: why can't you do `NDSolve[(* stuff *), {r, rinf, rinf}, (* more stuff *)]`?

Comment: included initial conditions and the value of M now...omega seems to get worse from about maybe 5. I will include the other solution with ICs set at infinity later, as that one is actually much worse, but the code is more complicated. J.M tried to answer your question in a comment on your answer.

Comment: BTW: since your `b[n]` satisfies a three-term recurrence, you might want to look into using Clenshaw summation to evaluate `uintrunc[]`.

Comment: Is there any scope for using Compile here? (I've only just learned about it so maybe it's totally not the place but just wondering)

Comment: Alternative is to subsample the solution - this will use far less memory. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/ndsolve-sampling-for-result-during-the-computation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to integrate over quite a large range (10,000) and that is part of the problem, but I actually only need the value of the `InterpolatingFunction[]` produced at the end point. Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* I just want this last point?

One way to go about it is to have the start and end of the integration interval be identical. Consider the following:

```
y[5] /. First @ NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 5, 5}]
   0.07731217497157500942
```

To see that the approach saves space, here's a comparison:

```
yi = y /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 5, 5}];
ByteCount[yi]
   1296

yn = y /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}];
ByteCount[yn]
   3288
```

Comment: thanks but that won't work for me. I should have mentioned that I need to set up some initial conditions at a certain radius (the dependent variable) and then integrate outwards to a large distance, and it's the point at large r where I need the solutions. But I don't need the rest of the 10,000, so Mathematica could dump it, as soon as it gets enough data to leap frog to the next point if you see what I mean.

Comment: Right; that's why I suggested that you have the start and end points be the same. If you'll edit your question to show the `NDSolve[]` snippet that you say has taxed your memory, I can edit my answer to match.

Comment: that's not possible, the IC for the solution I want have to start at a certain radius (the event horizon) and I integrate it out to the "infinity". The solution with ICs set at the infinity and integrated inwards are different, and there is no known way to set the ICs anywhere else..Sorry if that's not a clear explanation, but that much at least is a given in my problem: ICs must be at r=2, point I want must be at r=10000. Edited my post now that should be a working example. Try large omega values to observe the lag.

Comment: `NDSolve[]` will still start at the initial condition you gave (in your new example, `Φ[rH] == (* stuff *)`); as mentioned in the docs, the integration interval supplied need not contain the value in the initial conditions, and `NDSolve[]` will go forward or backward as appropriate. That's why I don't understand why you say this won't work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh, actually, sorry I misunderstood you, maybe that will work then if NDSolve behaves like that. I didn't realise it could skip forward/backward. Unfortunately I have to dash now, but I will try this ASAP. thanks.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to show a Timing improvement? but maybe there is a memory improvement. I agree that the final interpolating function produced is smaller, but does that also mean NDSolve is using less memory in the process of getting to the result?

Comment: I also added the other solution where we do integrate from infinity (r=10000) ICs, and I need to use NDSolve to go the other way down to r=2 say. This is the one that NDSolve is really struggling with for large omega..

Comment: For your second case, you modify the `NDSolve[]` call appropriately: `NDSolve[{eq, Φ[10000] == ...}, Φ, {r, 2, 2}, opts]`.

Comment: "hmm, doesn't seem to show a Timing improvement?" - this is an equation with an oscillatory solution, after all; some amount of effort has to be expended. :)

Comment: perhaps, and if the method you suggest stops memory death that is at least something.

Comment: What about my use of StiffnessSwitching? I'm not really sure what I'm doing with this, but it seems to increase speed, although accuracy is lost. Could there be a case for another method like RungeKutta?

Comment: Well, `"StiffnessSwtiching"` uses two different versions of the Bulirsch-Stoer extrapolation scheme as the stiff and nonstiff component integrators. You could try something like `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "ImplicitRungeKutta"}}`, but you should known that RK methods are less efficient than extrapolative methods for high-accuracy computations. If you don't need too much accuracy (e.g. having only six good digits is fine), then sure, use RK.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6110/discussion-between-fpghost-and-j-m)

Comment: @J.M. But using the same start and end point for the interval for NDSolve would result in the same amount of run time, using just lesser memory then....?

Comment: @drN, yes, you still expend the same amount of effort; after all, you still have to do all those evaluations to get to where you want to be.