# NDSolve - sampling for result during the computation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am using NDSolve for a Langevin dynamics problem. I want to the know long term behaviour of my system ($t>1$) but it has to be simulated with very small time steps ($dt\sim 10^{-9}$). An example code:

```
R[t_Real]:= RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]]

NDSolve[
  {(-x''[t] - k1*x'[t] + k2*R[t])==0, x[0]==0, x'[0]==0} //.values,
  x,
  {t, 0, 10},
  StartingStepSize-> 10^-9,
  Method->{"FixedStep",Method->"ExplicitEuler"},
  MaxSteps->\[Infinity]
]
```

**The Problem:** My computer runs out memory when trying to store $10^{10}$ data points necessary for this computation. Is there a way to sample and store only a small subset of all the integration points?

Comment: Have you tried [Mma's RandomVariate[...]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomVariate.html)? What does `values` do? Is there a reason you are using `ExplicitEuler`? You would benefit by letting Mathematica choose the solver automatically or use perhaps the magic-wand `Method->"LSODA"`. Also, why not just let t range from 0 to a very large number (for long term behavior)?

Comment: Hi, the 'values' variable is used to store parameters k1 and k2. I do not trust the automatic solvers of Mathematica because 'R[t]' is not a continuos function. For me $t \sim 1$ is a long time behaviour. The problem presented here has a damping of momentum (second term) that happens on the timescale of $10^{-9}$. The momentum has to relax from thermal kicks obtained from 'R[t]' term. For this reason I am using constant time sampling.

Comment: May I ask if this molecular dynamics or some such? What is the physical phenomena that you are trying to model?

Comment: It is a simple 1D Molecular Dynamics model for free diffusion

Comment: I performed simulations on MD for my Master's degree and I am curious, if you don't mind. Are you simulating Argon? With periodic BCs? Is the eqn you are solving the convection-diffusion equation? In 2012 I had a similar question on SE and I am wondering if [it would help you](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3635/204). Good luck!

Comment: Have you considered doing the simulation piece by piece i.e. first calculate `{t, 0, 10^-4}`, then `{t, 10^-4, 2 10^-4}` and so on?

Comment: @xzczd Didn't know one could do that. However, how would one control the time step size? I imagine it would be thro' `MaxStepFraction` or `MaxStepSize`?

Comment: @drN OP has chosen method [`"FixedStep"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html), so the step size can be controlled by `StartingStepSize`, I think `MaxStepFraction` and `MaxStepSize` will also work (haven't tested yet), but I don't know how to control time step size in more general cases (for example PDEs), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have `NDSolve` do the integration but not save the results (set second argument to `{}`).  Then use [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) to save points at whatever interval `dt` you please.  This uses much less memory; in fact for `dt = 10^-2`, the memory use is negligible for the settings below.

Since parameters were not given by the OP, I used the simplest choices.  Also, waiting for ten billion steps seemed silly for a proof-of-concept trial, so I lengthened the step size.

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

SeedRandom[1];
R[t_Real] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
values = {k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1};

lastt = -1;
dt = 10^-2;

{foo, {pts}} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{(-x''[t] - k1*x'[t] + k2*R[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0} /. values,
    {}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxSteps -> ∞,
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[t >= lastt + dt, lastt = t; Sow[{t, x[t]}]]
    ];
sol = Interpolation[pts];

MaxMemoryUsed[]

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]

(* 37243360 *)

(* 37243360 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When the integral `x` is requested, the memory use by `NDSolve` is significantly higher:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

SeedRandom[1];
R[t_Real] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
values = {k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1};

lastt = -1;
dt = 10^-2;

{foo, {pts}} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{(-x''[t] - k1*x'[t] + k2*R[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0} /. values,
    x, {t, 0, 10}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxSteps -> ∞,
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[t >= lastt + dt, lastt = t; Sow[{t, x[t]}]]
    ];
sol = Interpolation[pts];

MaxMemoryUsed[]

Plot[x[t] /. First[foo] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]

(* 37243360 *)

(* 127874624 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]