# NDSolve for 2d Langevin equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, stochastic-calculus

I want to simulate the movement of a damped single particle which vibrates due to Brownian motion.

$m \ddot{x} + \gamma \dot{x} - \xi(t)=0$

where $\gamma$ is the friction constant and $\xi(t)$ a "random" or "fluctuating force".

In principle I would like to solve a similar equation as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/ndsolve-sampling-for-result-during-the-computation) but I would like to get out the (x,y) coordinate pairs and how they vary with time.

So, **how can I extend the 1d Langevin equation so that `NDSolve` produces the 2d coordinates**?

This is the **answer** from [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/ndsolve-sampling-for-result-during-the-computation) for the **1d problem**:

```
SeedRandom[1];
R[t_Real] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
values = {k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1};

lastt = -1;
dt = 10^-2;

{foo, {pts}} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{(-x''[t] - k1*x'[t] + k2*R[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0} /. values,
    x, {t, 0, 10}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxSteps -> ∞,
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[t >= lastt + dt, lastt = t; Sow[{t, x[t]}]]
    ];

Plot[x[t] /. First[foo] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension of your answer seems to work. I have taken out the evaluation monitor since it is not used in the plot.

```
SeedRandom[1];
R[t_Real] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
values = {k1x -> 1, k2x -> 1,k1y -> 1, k2y -> 1};

foo=NDSolve[{
    (-x''[t] - k1x*x'[t] + k2x*R[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0,
    (-y''[t] - k1y*y'[t] + k2y*R[t]) == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1} /.values,
    {x[t],y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 10^-3, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxSteps -> Infinity
];

(* plot in x-y plane  *)
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t]}/.foo[[1]]],{t,0,10}]
(* plot with time on z axis  *)
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t],t}/.foo[[1]]],{t,0,10},BoxRatios->{1,1,1}]
```

Comment: Why is the effective displacement much larger in x than in y? That should not be in average. The movement is somehow directed, what is unclear to me.

Comment: @Lenoil Actually the displacement is much larger in y, that's because ha loa chooses `x'[0] == 0` and `y'[0] == 1` as the i.c.. And I believe $F$ should also be a vector if you need undirected result.